# Sending http.get with special characters in path

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to add users to my subscriber list on what counts, but I keep having issues sending the request. I keep getting errors no matter which method I choose (curl,request,http). The errors always seem to be yelling at me for the url (but I know the url works). Any help would be appreciated

suscribe: function(req,res){

```
    var callback = function(err, response, body){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            console.log(url);
            res.status(400);
            res.send(err);
        }else{
            res.status(response);
            res.send('OK');
        }
    };

    //Builds command
    var url = "http://secure.whatcounts.com/bin/api_web";
    url += "?cmd=subscribe";
    url += "&r=company";
    url += "&pwd=pwd";
    url +="&list_id=23508";
    url += "&data=email,custom_special^" + req.body.email;
    url += ",special+text";

    request(url.format(url), callback);
},
```

error

```
TypeError: Object http://secure.whatcounts.com/bin/api_web?cmd=subscribe&r=company&pwd=pwd&list_id=23508&data=email,custom_special^pnchappy92@gmail.com,special+text has no method 'format'
    at module.exports.suscribe (c:\Users\pchapman\Documents\sparc\controllers\landing.js:36:21)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\Users\pchapman\Documents\sparc\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
    at next (c:\Users\pchapman\Documents\sparc\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:110:13)
    at Route.dispatch (c:\Users\pchapman\Documents\sparc\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:91:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\Users\pchapman\Documents\sparc\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
    at c:\Users\pchapman\Documents\sparc\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:267:22
    at Function.proto.process_params (c:\Users\pchapman\Documents\sparc\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:321:12)
    at next (c:\Users\pchapman\Documents\sparc\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:261:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\pchapman\Documents\sparc\node_modules\express-session\index.js:421:7)
    at Object.immediate._onImmediate (timers.js:363:16)
```

Comment: http://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_format_urlobj

Comment: BTW, what exactly error says?

Comment: I updated the code and error

Comment: Of course string `url` doesn't have method `format`. I guess, you've overwrite node's module `url`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting the `url` module with your `url` string. Just use a different variable name and it should work:

```
//Builds command
var urlstr = "http://secure.whatcounts.com/bin/api_web";
urlstr += "?cmd=subscribe";
urlstr += "&r=company";
urlstr += "&pwd=pwd";
urlstr +="&list_id=23508";
urlstr += "&data=email,custom_special^" + req.body.email;
urlstr += ",special+text";

request(url.format(urlstr), callback);
```